# git-http-backend with lighttpd not able to access repository

Tags: git, webserver, lighttpd

I'm trying to set up a git repo on my webserver.
As I don't want to give everyone ssh access I'd like to use the http-backend.

Here is the configuration of lighttpd that I use:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "git.domain.org" {
  alias.url               += ( "/git" => "/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend")
  # prevent a request to "/git" from causing a 500 error (no PATH_INFO)
  url.rewrite-once         = ( "^/git$" => "/git/" )

  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/git/" {
    # turn on CGI unconditionally for this URL
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
    setenv.add-environment = (
      "GIT_PROJECT_ROOT" => "/home/<username>/git/",
      "GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL" => ""
    )
  }
}
```

When trying to clone ( git clone http://git.domain.org/git/test.git ) the repo the following error appears:

```
fatal: http://git.domain.org/git/test.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

The responding repos lays in /home/username/git/test.git .

Any ideas how to fix this?
As I try to do this on a rented webserver I don't have superuser access.

Comment: superuser access may not be required, what is the command you are executing

Comment: @Bijendra git clone http://git.domain.org/git/test.git

Answer (score 0):

If you are running opensuse, since your gitroot is not in /srv/git, you need to update apparmor to allow read access of your gitrepo.

edit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.share.git-web.gitweb.cgi
and add /home/username/git and /home/username/git/** to the existing list.